# gzip encoded responses doesn't decode

Tags: php, apache, encoding, gzip

I use gzip encoding in php:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
echo json_encode($arr);
ob_end_flush();
```

It works locally on my OpenServer, but uploaded to production it doesn't get decoded by browser.

I get

```
‹мќ]s›8Зї ГЕs±"...
```

instead of json object. Where can be an issue?

Prod headers:

```
Server: nginx/1.2.6
Date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 11:30:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1251
Content-Length: 3661
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Local headers:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:4066
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 08 Sep 2015 11:30:57 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.27 (Win32)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: uh oh: 2010 strikes back: [Unsupported PHP-Branches](https://secure.php.net/eol.php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the exact problem in your case is; however, you might want to consider using [`gzencode`](http://php.net/gzencode):

```
echo gzencode(json_encode($arr));
```

No need for output buffering here.

If you're sending the result to a browser directly, don't forget to set the correct headers. If your browser still shows garbage, you should check with something like Firebug or DevTools if the header was really set.

Comment: I use it for ajax requests, as I understood browser automaticaly decodes it when he sees header Content-Encoding:gzip.   With gzencode it doesnt decode it on my local server also and Content-Encoding:gzip is absent

Comment: I added headers to my initial question. Looks like they are correct?